# Error with Asp.net checkbox list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, vb.net-2010

Im having a problem with my checkbox list. I'm able to loop though it, but I can not seem to find that items are checked. Im coding this in VB.net 2010 and asp.net In my for each i always get False on selected.

Here is some of my code:

```
Protected Sub cmdSend_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSend.Click
    'Check for checked users. 
    Dim lqText As New lqAlarmAndGoDataContext

    Try
        For Each foundCheckedUser In cbMembers.Items
            If foundCheckedUser.Selected Then
                Dim objText As New tbTxtMessageQueue
                With objText
                    .TxtFrom = "txt@123.com"
                    .TxtTo = foundCheckedUser.value
                    .TxtBoddy = tbMessage.Text
                    .SentFlag = False
                End With
                lqText.tbTxtMessageQueues.InsertOnSubmit(objText)
                lqText.SubmitChanges()
            End If
          Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you load the checkedlistbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you bind your data to the checkbox?

Make sure it's not being rebinded before the button onclick by using

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
```

Also, make sure your viewstate are enabled

Answer (score 2):

Are you rebinding `cbMembers` on each postback?  That will cause your selection info to be lost.  Try refactoring your code so that `cbMembers` only gets bound once.